# PayPal IPN subscription

Tags: php, paypal, subscription, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

is there a way to set up paypal IPN so it will trigger my script every time there are changes on my paypal account. Such as new payments, canceling subscription, recurring payments etc?

I understand that it's just a couple of modification to the script posted on paypal for developers webby. However, I'm having troubles testing the script using their sandbox. It seems that it resets the connection and the settings for IPN, the subscription buttons etc.

Is there anybody who can help with a script or manual?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the IPN listener code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I have used IPN successfully in the past. Getting it work was a right b$!@#, I feel your pain.

I didn't know IPN could also be used for anything other than payment notifications.

In the sandbox environment you should have a separate account, make sure you set it up correctly.